# Retrieve "id" as list from browse record of many2many field?

Tags: python, odoo

I want to extract id from the browse record in to a list.

```
user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users') 
user_values = user_obj.browse(cr, uid, uid)
print user_values.company_ids
```

is `[browse_record(res.company, 36), browse_record(res.company, 30)]`

I tried `br_record.company_ids[0][1]`

I want a id's in a `list_id = [36, 30]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`br_record` is a list so you need to index into it.
Indexing into `br_record` returns a `browse_record`.
I'm assuming `browse_record` has an `id` field.

So to access a single record:

```
br_record[0].id == 36
```

To construct the list of ids you can use a list comprehension:

```
list_id = [br.id for br in user_obj.browse(cr, uid, uid).company_ids]
```